# How can I view the posts in the middle of the "[1][2][3][4][5] ... [28760]" pages?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-experience, pagination

How can I view the post here?

[image: numbers]

As far as I know, I'll have to keep on clicking and waiting for it to load.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the expected way is to keep clicking to navigate to the page immediately before the ellipsis (…), which will load a new set of page links.

However, you can always manually manipulate the page number appearing in the slug (`&page=8`) in the URL in your browser's address bar.

If you're willing to install a userscript, you can use my [HoverExpandNavigationLinks](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/HoverExpandNavigationLinks.user.js) script, which automatically adds the links to in-between pages when you hover over the ellipsis:

[image: Demo of HoverExpandNavigationLinks userscript in operation]

Comment: That's the whole point of a userscript: it automatically injects JavaScript into the loaded page. You can paste the same code manually into the console and it will work, but it will not persist across page loads or even refreshes, which makes this mighty inconvenient.